# I think I once asked a question on about terminal aerodrome forecasts (TAFs), which may have been deleted. True or false?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, deleted-questions

I think I may have once asked a question on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, about terminal aerodrome forecasts (TAFs), though I'm not sure if I was logged in as "unforgettableid" or as someone else.

I can't find it anymore. Maybe it was deleted.

Do I appear to have really asked such a question? If so, was it closed? And if it was — why?

[**Edit:** I found the question, in a text file saved on this computer. D'oh! I have now posted it. See: ["To know what time it may rain, I like TAF forecasts. I'd like the embedded times converted to local time and 12-hour notation."](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/to-know-what-time-it-may-rain-i-like-taf-forecasts-id-like-the-embedded-times) Feel free to delete this meta question if you like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted anything as of the time of this writing with the account you used to post this meta question.

It's possible that you used a different account to post it, but I'm on mobile at the moment and can't investigate very far right now. When I get home I'll look closer.